# PHP dividir cadena y crear un array

Tags: php

Buenas quiero extraer en cadenas separadas un string con PHP no sé que método utilizar, ami documento `.php` me envían por medio de `AJAX` una cadena similar a la siguiente:

```
?i=0&edad=18_28&tarifa=40_80,81_110&servicio=25&ubicacion=1,4
```

Ahora bien más que todo lo que quiero es extraer las cadenas que se encuentran entre los `&` y guardarlas en variables o array osea que quede de la siguiente forma:

```
id=0
edad=18_28
tarifa=40_48,81_110
servicio=25
ubicacion=1,4
```

Tomando en cuenta que NO siempre estarán todas aveces, puede estar edad y tarifa pero no ubicación, por favor ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para eso se usa [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) le pasas el string y un array para almacenar las cosas.

```
<?php

    $cosas =[];
    $urlString ="?i=0&edad=18_28&tarifa=40_80,81_110&servicio=25&ubicacion=1,4";
    // sacamos el ?
    $urlString = ltrim($urlString,'?');
    // parseamos al array
    parse_str($urlString, $cosas);
    // imprimimos a ver que hay
    var_dump($urlString, $cosas);
```

---

resultado:

```
string(60) "i=0&edad=18_28&tarifa=40_80,81_110&servicio=25&ubicacion=1,4"
array(5) {
  ["i"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["edad"]=>
  string(5) "18_28"
  ["tarifa"]=>
  string(12) "40_80,81_110"
  ["servicio"]=>
  string(2) "25"
  ["ubicacion"]=>
  string(3) "1,4"
}
```

ver [online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/103489c32085bb97c13fd4417d908d8fa5cd37f2)

Comment: Muchas gracias, exactamente lo que buscaba :)